# Need help doing simple rendering with Qt5 Qml + OpenGL

Tags: qt, opengl, qml, qt5

I need to make it so part of my Qml view is “taken over” by some non-Qt OpenGL rendering, and I was having issues getting a texture to display properly so I thought I would just draw a line and get that to work before moving on to more complicated code.

For those not familiar with Qt5, the entire window is drawn using OpenGL, and I'm hooking into Qt's OpenGL drawing mechanism using their QQuickWindow::beforeRendering() signal which means my painting code is executed every redraw (every vertical sync).

I took the Squircle sample code ( http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-example.html ) and modified it slightly so it would draw in a specified portion of the screen (instead of the entire screen) and that is working perfectly. Then, I modified just the renderer::paint() function to initially draw three green lines, and after 2 seconds to instead draw one blue line:

```
void CtRenderer::paint()
{
static int n = 0;

if (n == 0)
{
    glViewport(m_rect.x() + 10, m_rect.y() + 10, m_rect.width() - 20, m_rect.height() - 20);

    glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    glScissor(m_rect.x() + 10, m_rect.y() + 10, m_rect.width() - 20, m_rect.height() - 20);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

    // glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    // glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLineWidth(10);
    glColor4f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 1);        glVertex3f(1, 0.5, 1);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 1);        glVertex3f(0.5, 0.5, 1);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 1);        glVertex3f(0.5, 1, 1);
    glEnd();
}
else if (n == 120)
{
    glViewport(m_rect.x() + 10, m_rect.y() + 10, m_rect.width() - 20, m_rect.height() - 20);

    glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    glScissor(m_rect.x() + 10, m_rect.y() + 10, m_rect.width() - 20, m_rect.height() - 20);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

    // glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    // glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glLineWidth(10);
    glColor4f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 1);        glVertex3f(0.4, 0.8, 1);
    glEnd();

}
n++;

return;
```

}`

What I get instead are three gray lines that flicker continuously and never change to being a single line. After some online research, I thought that maybe I should not use glBegin()/glEnd() so I changed the code :

```
void CtRenderer::paint()
{
static bool bOnce = true;

if (bOnce)
{
    glViewport(m_rect.x() + 10, m_rect.y() + 10, m_rect.width() - 20, m_rect.height() - 20);

    glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
    glScissor(m_rect.x() + 10, m_rect.y() + 10, m_rect.width() - 20, m_rect.height() - 20);

    float vertices[] = {-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f};

    glLineWidth(10);
    glColor4f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1);

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);

    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 2);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    bOnce = false;
}

return;
}
```

This still gives me a flickering gray line.

When I try this code in a simple GLUT application, outside of Qt, it works just fine, so it seems to be some interaction between OpenGL and Qt5 Qml.  What can I try next?

p.s. I'm using Qt version 5.3 on a Linux Ubuntu box

p.p.s. In response to some comments, I updated my code to look like this:

```
void dumpGlErrors(int iLine)
{
for (;;)
{
    GLenum err = glGetError();
    if (err == GL_NO_ERROR)
        return;
    std::cout << "GL error " << err << " detected in line " << iLine << std::endl;
}
}

void CtRenderer::paint()
{
glPushMatrix();

glLoadIdentity();

glViewport(m_rect.x() + 10, m_rect.y() + 10, m_rect.width() - 20, m_rect.height() - 20);

glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
glScissor(m_rect.x() + 10, m_rect.y() + 10, m_rect.width() - 20, m_rect.height() - 20);

dumpGlErrors(__LINE__);

glClearColor(1, 0, 1, 1);       // Magenta
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

bool bDepth = glIsEnabled(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

bool bLighting = glIsEnabled(GL_LIGHTING);
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

bool bTexture = glIsEnabled(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

dumpGlErrors(__LINE__);

float vertices[] = { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.1f,  0.5f, 0.5f, 0.1f,  0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f };
float colors[] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

glLineWidth(10);
glColor4f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);

glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors);

dumpGlErrors(__LINE__);

glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 4);       // 4, not 2.

dumpGlErrors(__LINE__);

// glFlush();

glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

if (bTexture)
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

if (bLighting)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

if (bDepth)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glPopMatrix();

dumpGlErrors(__LINE__);

// In case somebody else calls glClear()
glClearColor(0, 1, 1, 1);       // Cyan
}
```

Now I get a nice magenta background and I see my line flash once and then it goes away and I'm left with only magenta.

p.p.p.s.  I tried using VBO type functions:

```
class Point
{
public:
float m_vertex[3];
float m_color[4];
};

void SquircleRenderer::drawBuffer()
{
QOpenGLFunctions glFuncs(QOpenGLContext::currentContext());

if (!m_bBufInit)
{
    std::cout << "SquircleRenderer::drawBuffer()" << std::endl;
    // Adding these two lines doesn't change anything
    /*
    glFuncs.initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    glFuncs.glUseProgram(0);
    */

    // Create a new VBO
    glFuncs.glGenBuffers(1, &m_buf);

    // Make the new VBO active
    glFuncs.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_buf);

    static const Point points[4] = {
        { { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.1f }, { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } },
        { {  0.5f,  0.5f, 0.1f }, { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } },
        { {  0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f }, { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f } },
        { {  0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f } }
    };

    // Upload vertex data to the video device
    glFuncs.glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * sizeof(Point), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    dumpGlErrors(__LINE__);

    m_bBufInit = true;
}

glPushMatrix();

glLoadIdentity();

glViewport(m_rect.x() + 10, m_rect.y() + 10, m_rect.width() - 20, m_rect.height() - 20);

glEnable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);
glScissor(m_rect.x() + 10, m_rect.y() + 10, m_rect.width() - 20, m_rect.height() - 20);

glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 1);       // Yellow
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glFuncs.glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_buf);

dumpGlErrors(__LINE__);

/*
 * "If a non-zero named buffer object is bound to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER target
 *  (see glBindBuffer) while a vertex array is
 *  specified, pointer is treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store"
 */

glLineWidth(10);
glColor4f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Point), 0);

glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Point), (void*)offsetof(Point, m_color));

dumpGlErrors(__LINE__);

glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 4);       // 4, not 2.

dumpGlErrors(__LINE__);

glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

// In case somebody else calls glClear()
glClearColor(0, 1, 1, 1);       // Cyan

glPopMatrix();

dumpGlErrors(__LINE__);
}
```

As with all my other efforts, I get a yellow background and my lines appear for what I assume is 1/60 second before the lines disappear and all I have is my yellow background.

Comment: You might be missing the `glClear...` part from theSquircle code.

Comment: If I add "glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);" and "glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);" after the glScissor(), I get a flickering green background in addition to the flickering gray line.  Strangely, the green background is semi-transparent even though the alpha to glColor is 1.

Comment: It appears semi-transparent cause your eye can't keep up. And your problem is due to the single paint you do while you have two buffers (front and back). The first paint call update the back buffer, then the buffers are swapped, then you recall paint, but it does nothing because your `if` doesn't pass. The buffer is swapped again, so black buffer. then reswap, green + line. Then swapped again and so on. If you set b0unce as n `int` equals to 0 and your if checks below 2, it should work.

Comment: concerning the color, consider yourself lucky to have a white line (not grey, once again, it's just your eye that can't keep up). `glColor4f` doesn't work with `glDrawArrays` I think. Give a try to `glColorPointer`. It works as `glVertexPointer`, I never used it though, the fixed pipeline is a wonder to me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I tried to implement them all and as you can see (I edited my main post) the results are different but still not quite right.

Comment: Since it appears once then disappear, I wonder what happens between the first and second `paint()` call. First I would check `CtRenderer::paint()` is called more than once (maybe `glClear` is called repeatedly from somewhere else with the `glClearColor` you defined). A breakpoint will do the trick. If the `paint()` is called more than once, I would check `glError()` is alright at the end of the function, if not find the culprit. If `glError` is fine, check the program you use is 0 (default fixed pipeline). I have more ideas but try this first. Keep the p.p.s. code, easier to analyze.

Comment: [1] My paint() function is called every vertical sync.  [2] I've added code to check glGetError() all over the place, and it always returns zero.  [3] I'm inside a Qt5 application, and Qt is creating the GL context and pipeline so I can't tell you more about them.  Are there GL calls to ask what kind of pipeline is in use?

Comment: If you do nothing else, the default shader program should still be in use. My last call would be your MVP matrix. I see in the last ppps you do a push and pop. Do you play with the projection/model/view matrices somewhere ? It could be you move after the first rendering, putting the line out of the frustum.

Comment: I added some glLoadIdentity() calls which didn't help (see the code above), is there anything else I need to do to reset the matrices?

Comment: At this point I'm out of ideas. I'll just write the answer modifying the Squircle code so you can draw your 3lines then just 1 and you move forward from that. Since you're using pieces of the Legacy OpenGL I'm a bit confused and can't give more backed up advices.

Comment: @BettyCrokker could you share the code you used to modify the `Squircle` program to only draw part of the screen?

Comment: A little set of simple examples with Qt and QML I am working on can be found here https://gitlab.com/MrMuffin/openglunderqml. I hope it help you :)

Answer (score 4):

I discovered the answer: I have to tell Qt that I'm using the old fixed function pipeline.  Making one function call before doing any drawing does the trick:

```
QOpenGLFunctions glFuncs(QOpenGLContext::currentContext());
glFuncs.glUseProgram(0);
```

Comment: "check the program you use is 0 (default fixed pipeline)". I did asked you to check this though. I should have been more clear about what function to call. Don't use the fixed pipeline -> []

Comment: Reading back over the discussion, I see this now!  At the time I didn't know what a pipeline was, so I couldn't do much with the information.  Even the answer I did eventually find I kind of stumbled into ... I found some code that worked, and it had this magic function call at the top, and I tried it and it worked.  But you were of great help to me, and I am happy to give you the bounty!

Answer (score 1):

With Qt Quick there are three ways you can mix OpenGL:

1. You can draw *under* the (entire) QML (see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-openglunderqml-example.html)
2. You can draw *over* the (entire) QML
3. You can supply an OpenGL texture that is drawn on a QML element (see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsgsimpletexturenode.html)

Alternatively you can build a QWidget application and use OpenGL in a QWidget window and QML in another (QML widget window).

Comment: The Squircle code (on which my painting is based) uses the OpenGL Under QML style. I would like to draw Qt items on top of my OpenGL (like labels) so #2 isn't good for me, and eventually I'm going to have a rather complex OpenGL rendering which I would rather not convert to a texture and back to Open GL (too much swapping between GPU and CPU).  So my question is not _which_ method of mixing OpenGL should I use, but how can I get this specific method to work.

Comment: Indeed, I see now you specifically mentioned that you started with the Squircle draw-under sample.

Comment: Do you have an example of #2 (drawing OVER qml)?  I'm not finding much.  I'm interested in that because I have a SceneGraph (also based on the Squircle example) and then a Qt3D RenderSettings whose `ClearBuffer` is erasing my SceneGraph, and I'm not sure how to have both show, or put my scene graph over Qt3D's scenegraph.

Comment: A reply to my previous comment above:  I made a mistake when I initially tried this, but it turns out to be literally as simple as changing the connection form the `beforeRendering` event to `afterRendering`

Answer (score 0):

```
void SquircleRenderer::paint()
{
    if (!m_program) {
        m_program = new QOpenGLShaderProgram();
        m_program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex,
                                           "attribute highp vec4 aVertices;"
                                           "attribute highp vec4 aColors;"
                                           "varying highp vec4 vColors;"
                                           "void main() {"
                                           "    gl_Position = aVertices;"
                                           "    vColors= aColors;"
                                           "}");
        m_program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment,
                                           "varying highp vec4 vColors;"
                                           "void main() {"
                                           "    gl_FragColor = vColors;"
                                           "}");

        m_program->bindAttributeLocation("aVertices", 0);
        m_program->bindAttributeLocation("aColors", 1);
        m_program->link();

    }

    m_program->bind();

    m_program->enableAttributeArray(0);
    m_program->enableAttributeArray(1);

    float vertices[] = {
        -1, -1, //Diag bottom left to top right
        1, 1,
        -1, 1, //Diag top left to bottom right
        1, -1,
        -1, 0, //Horizontal line
        1, 0
    };
    float colors[] = {
        1, 1, 0, 1, 
        1, 0, 1, 1,
        0, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 0, 0, 1,
        0, 0, 1, 1,
        0, 1, 0, 1
    };
    m_program->setAttributeArray(0, GL_FLOAT, vertices, 2); //3rd to 0, 4th to 1 by default
    m_program->setAttributeArray(1, GL_FLOAT, colors, 4); 

    glViewport(0, 0, m_viewportSize.width(), m_viewportSize.height());

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //Here I draw 3 lines, reduce to 2 instead of 6 to draw only one.
    //Change second param to choose which line to draw
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 6);

    m_program->disableAttributeArray(0);
    m_program->disableAttributeArray(1);
    m_program->release();
}
```

My conclusion would be to leave the Legacy version of OpenGL in the history book. Even if it's for dummy shaders like those one, it saves you the trouble of managing any matrices and you know what is happening.

PS : The code hasn't been tested, it's just a tweak of the Squircle code. Let me know if there is trouble, but I'd rather continue the troubleshoot session from this piece of code.